# I have problem with CORS with SpringBoot 3 and angular

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, cors

I have tried everything i found on the internet nothing seems to work. I am using Spring boot 3 and angular 16. Its weird because a simple get request works that returns a string.

console error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/signin' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {
//    @Bean
//    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfig() {
//        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
//            @Override
//            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
//                registry.addMapping("/api/v1/**")
//                        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")  
//                        .allowedMethods("*")
//                        .allowedHeaders("*") 
//                        .allowCredentials(true);
//            }
//        };
//    }
    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();

        
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:4200");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);

        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
}
```

tried all of this like i said works for a simple get request. The backend works fine i tested it with postman.
FRONTEND

```
  private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1'

  private headers
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private userService: UserService) {

    this.headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
      
  }
  
 login(email: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.post<LoginResponse>(
      `${this.apiUrl}/signin`,
      {
        email: email,
        password: password
      },
      { observe: 'response' }
    ).pipe(
      map((response: HttpResponse<LoginResponse>) => {
        const token = response.body?.token;
        console.log('Token:', token);
        return response;
      })
    );
  }
```

i triple checked the urls, the data types, that my login form i giving back the right variables. This is not my first time using spring an angular. But i have always used Spring boot 2 prior. The only part that i am not  completely familiar that could be causing the problem would be this class below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig  {
    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    private final UserService userService;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService.userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return authProvider;
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf
                        .disable()
                )
                .sessionManagement(session -> session
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                )
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/signup", "/api/v1/signin", "/api/v1/bizsignin","/api/v1/bizsignup").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/v1/test/**","/api/v1/greetings").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider()).addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWjyQ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isOeq.png)
The successful and failed request

Answer (score 1):

i do this for development spring boot/angular

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{

@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
            .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your preflight request is not authorized (just a 401 on the `OPTIONS` request.

Preflight request are not supposed to contain authorization (and most frontend frameworks don't set an `Authorization` header on `OPTIONS` requests) but Spring auto-configured nothing ro `permitAll` the `OPRIONS` requests sent to resources configured to allow CORS. You have to do it yourself.